# NSObject released after layoutSubviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

First I have a class inherited from `NSObject`

```
@interface Role : NSObject{ /*...*/ } @end
```

And there is a property to store the pointer of the instant for `Role` class.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Role * role;
```

Now when the `UIView` created, I initialize an instant of the `Role` class.

```
Role * r = [[Role alloc] init];
role = r;
[r release];
```

As I understand, the property `role` is marked with `retian`, then it will automatically increase the reference count when I set the value, and decrease the reference count when the property is set to nil when the application exit.

Everything looks fine but when I run the application, I found that I will get EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

I added `NSLog` and this is because the `Role` instant has been `released` and `dealloced` after the `UIView` call `layoutSubviews`, I can't understand why this happen because I DO NOT have any code to `release` this instant.

Current temporarily solution for me is: I comments out the line `[r release]`

Please can someone give me some explanation if there is some background I don't know for `layoutSubviews`?

Thanks

Comment: In order to the property works you need to use it... so, use self.role = r;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing your ivar directly. This should have been:

```
self.role = r;
```

Avoid accessing your ivars directly; always use accessors except in `init` and `dealloc`.

Answer (score 2):

You should actually ***call the property "setter method" to retain the value***.

```
self.role = r;
```

or

```
[self setRole:r];
```